My Lenovo Chromebook is stuck on rabbit logo and never turns on, how to solve it?
I was trying to change the system language to Arabic on my laptop (its type and specifications are in the image)
Error 0x80070422 was showing up, I followed a YouTube guide to resolve it (link below) and it worked.
Booting Setting Interface Image
Rabbit logo image
https://youtu.be/Bs3HrXm7jZw?si=pGpiIiZIt6PVYKqD
What I did was opening "Events" and setting the startup type to "Automatic" then applying the change and pressing "Start" for each of the following:

Windows Event Collector

Window Event Log

Windows Update


After this I was able to download the language pack successfully but it wasn't get listed in "Display languages" to choose it
So I just "Restart" it and it never booted again.
I don't know if the changes I made caused this, but you should know that my internet connection was very bad. And when I restart the first time it said it is updating something and I shouldn't turn it off so I left it and it got stuck on the logo since.
I tried to turn it on several times again (I turned it off using the power button) but it is stuck every time.
I can open the booting setting by pressing "Esc" but I don't know if this can help
I hope you can help me
Thank you in advance

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
